# How to choose the size of a tablespace in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, tablespace

I want to create a tablespace for my database and the tables using this tablespace will have at least 15 MB of daily data inserted each day. Which type of tablespace (Bigfile or Small file) should I be using to store such data? And, what should be the initial size of the tablespace (SIZE parameter value)?

Answer (score 0):

Always use `smallfile` unless you have a specific reason not to. The initial size is up to you. You can allocate whatever you think will be the smallest amount of initial data, then set `autoextend` to a reasonable increment so that you don't have too many file growth operations going forward. Expanding the file slows down transactions, so keep the number of expansions low, like weekly or monthly, depending on your data insertion rate.